# Is there any way to use a case of a sum type as the type parameter of another type?

Tags: f#

Is there any way that I can do the following:

```
type First = |A |B

type Second = |C of First |D of A
```

In the above case, I want to specify D such that it can only contain a `First` of type `A` rather than any `First`. Is there any way I can impose this constraint in the declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `A` is a union case, which is a value, **not** a type. But the contents of each case require a type, which is why the code doesn't make sense. For the same reason, you can't create a function that takes a value of type `A` because it isn't a type. Let's fix that.

Suppose the case `A` contained some data (`A of int list list`). You could use a type alias to give a short or meaningful name to `int list list`. And then you can reuse the type name elsewhere:

```
type A = int list list

type First =
    | A of A
    | B

type Second =
    | C of First
    | D of A
```

Now you can also write a function which takes a value of type `A`.

It is a somewhat common practise to create a case which has the same name as the type that it contains (e.g. `A of A`). Just be clear on the distinction between the case `A` and the type `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Does this mean I will have to unbox a Second to get the A and rebox it to get a First every time I might want to pipe it to a function that uses a First?

Comment: Yes, but it's mostly intuitive. `match second with | C(A(a)) -> a | D(a) -> a`

Answer (score 1):

You can get something close with one extra step. You will need a common type that's shared by `A` in `First` and by `D` in `Second`:

```
type MyA =
| A

type First =
| A of MyA
| B

type Second =
| C of First
| D of MyA
```

This way you can make `First.A` and `Second.D` the same type.

Comment: While this would satisfy the representation, it does have a limitation. Since MyA is of type MyA and not of type A, it will not be able to be passed into functions taking in a First without wrapping it first. Is there any reason why the code in my example isn't allowed?